# Data Sharing Strategy Among Activities and Remote Service

Tags: android

I was wondering, is there any good data sharing strategy, among Activities, and a spawned remote service running in separate process. So far, I had tried 3 methods, none of them work.

### Use `Application`

I first thought, there will be only an `Application`, shared among 2 different processes, as their are origin from a single application.

But that is not the case. I realize, before a main `Activity` is created, an `Application` will be created. When I spawn a remote service, another new `Application` instance will be created too.

### Use `Preferences`

My first thought is that, this is a file based. So, whenever I write a value to `Preferences` through `sharedPreferences.edit().putString(key, value).commit()`, the change will be committed to file. Another process should be able to read the latest changes.

But this is not the case. My guess is that, this is because in my service, I acquire the `Preferences` instance only once during service start up through `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(application)`. It only read value from file during 1st time. Subsequent call `getString` will be read from memory.

### Use Global Static Variables

Not workable as `Activity` and remote `Service` are in 2 different processes. They are having 2 different memory spaces.

Any better strategy I can try out?

Comment: why don't you save data to txt file on sd card.Stupid solution since user can delete it but it can work if you don't expect this data to be  used once app closes

Comment: you can also try to persist data in sqlite

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you use one of two other options:

## 1: Broadcasts

Broadcasts with Context.sendBroadcast(Intent i) on one end, and a BroadcastReceiver defined with Context.registerReceiver(BroadcastReceiver b) on the other.

You can store quite a lot of data in the Intents, but access is extremely slow compared to direct use of in-memory variables.

## 2: Service binding

You can connect to a remote service across process boundaries if you define an interface to it with AIDL. It's a bit more complicated than the other options, but it is also the fastest option available. More information here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html